# refuses to save api key in build.gradle Module app

Tags: android, build.gradle, api-key

I've decided this is the best way because it keeps the key out the way if I upload to github.  However it never works, I add this to build.gradle Module app

```
        buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', 'blah blah'
    }
```

I don't know if it needs single or double quotes, I've tried both.

When I try to build the project it has a wobbler about BuildConfig.java,

```
    public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.newsreader.guardian.guardiantech";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
  // Fields from build type: debug
  public static final String API_KEY = sdjhgkjsdgsdkj-skdjhgsdkjsg-skjhskjsh;
```

It removes all the quotations, and says "Cannot resolve symbol".  It's a String so I've tried editing the quotation marks back in but the file refuses to save user changes.

Presumably I need to configure things differently in build.gradle?
Help!

Comment: `'"your key here"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to escape it. This line

```
it.buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', 'blah blah'
```

should be

```
it.buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', "\"blah blah\""
```

the values end up in a java class, so the syntax of the declaration of the members has to be respected. In your case, you are declaring a type String, and its initialization requires the string to be enclosed into a pair of `"`

Comment: Absolutely Jurassic!  Cheers.